# xpath to check the correct sequence of book-parts with @seq

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I am very new in XML development and I just read online materials to get me going so I'm really not an expert. I have a problem with my schematron file.

**Problem:** The schematron needs to check if every book-part is in sequence through @seq. However, my current schematron tagging doesn't work for nested book-parts.

**XML:**

```
<book>
  <meta>....</meta>
  <body>
     <book-part seq="1">....</book-part>
     <book-part seq="2">....</book-part>
     <book-part seq="3">
        <book-part-meta>....</book-part-meta>
        <book-body>
          <book-part seq="4">....</book-part>
          <book-part seq="5">....</book-part>
          <book-part seq="6">....</book-part>
        </book-body>
     </book-part>
     <book-part seq="7">
        <book-part-meta>....</book-part-meta>
        <book-body>
          <book-part seq="8">....</book-part>
          <book-part seq="9">....</book-part>
          <book-part seq="10">....</book-part>
        </book-body>
     </book-part>
     <book-part seq="11">....</book-part>
     <book-part seq="12">....</book-part>
 </body>
</book>
```

**Schematron tagging:**
 `<rule context="book-part[@seq]">
        <report role="error" test="preceding::book-part[@seq] and number(@seq) != (number(preceding::book-part[1]/@seq) + 1)">Book-parts must be in sequence</report>
      </rule>`

The schematron errors **book-part seq="4"** and **book-part seq="8"**. It seems that there is a problem with the first nested book-part. Is there someone that could help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing hierarchy levels here. What you need in this case is not only `preceding::` but also `parent::`. (For consistency, I think it should begin from 1 again on the sublevel, but that is only my personal opinion and not the point here.) You can test if `@seq` is correct by comparing it to the number of preceding and ancestor book-parts together:

```
<pattern id="test">
    <rule context="book-part[@seq]">
        <report role="error"
            test="number(@seq) != count(ancestor::book-part[@seq] | preceding::book-part[@seq]) + 1"
            >Book-parts must be numbered in sequence</report>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

I would treat the other condition (preceding book parts must have `@seq`) in a separate rule:

```
<pattern id="test2">
    <rule context="book-part[@seq]">
        <report role="error"
            test="preceding::book-part[not(@seq)] | ancestor::book-part[not(@seq)]"
            >Book-parts must be numbered</report>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

Comment: Oh yes, this seems more straightforward compare to what I have at the moment.

Comment: Much appreciated!